# Update the core and move current site in a sub-directory to the top level

Tags: installation, subsites

My main Drupal site is 8.6 but it is in a sub-directory. I want to update the core (to 8.9) and move the site up to the top level (public_html) overwriting an old site (in 6.1!) I no longer need.

Firstly, I will  of course  backup the database in phpMyAdmin.

I am not sure of the next steps.

My guess would be :

- delete everything under public_html except the sub-directory
- copy all files in the sub-directory up one level (to be under public_html)
- delete everything (including the now empty sub-directory)  under public_html except the sites, modules and themes folders
- unpack the Drupal  tar and copy core and vendor folders to public_html
- run update.php etc.
- settings.php in sites/default should be preserved
- copy in the provided .htaccess

Will this work? Have I missed anything?
All help appreciated,
thanks,
Rob

Comment: I would do the core upgrade first in the same directory, and then, once you have confirmed the updated site is up-to-date and working properly, then try to change the webroot.  Moving all the files + updating the site at the same time is just going to make it more difficult to troubleshoot if something goes wrong.

Comment: Yes thanks Patrick I just decided to it that way this very afternoon.